# Replace lockscreen with slideshow

Tags: android, lockscreen

Is it possible to replace the Android lockscreen with a slideshow of pictures? If so, can anyone tell me shortly which steps are needed for that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement LockActivity. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/wiki/LockActivity) is pretty good article how to implement it.